# Discord.py bot output to file python

Tags: python, discord

The program below should take a user token, get the bot Tag like: (discord-bot#0241) and output it to a file via a regex.

```py
import discord

RED, CYAN, GREEN, END = '\033[91m', '\033[36m', '\033[1;32m', '\033[0m'

client = discord.Client()

token = input('Token here: ')
filename = input('File name: ')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    botmaster = print(client.user)
    return botmaster


def config():   
    botToken = token
    botMaster = on_ready()
    print('\n[~] Configuration:\n [BOT TOKEN] =' + botToken + '\n [BOT MASTER] = ' + botMaster)
    confirm = input('\nConfirm ? (y/n) : ')
    if confirm.upper() == 'Y':
        info = 'botToken = ' + '\'' + botToken + '\'' +'\nbotMaster = ' + '\'' + botMaster + '\'' 
        with open('payload.py','r') as contents:
            save = contents.read()
        with open(fileName,'w') as contents:
            contents.write(info)
        with open(fileName,'a') as contents:
            contents.write(save)
        return('{0}[{1}*{0}]{1} Saved as ' + 'f{fileName}'.format(GREEN, END, RED))
    else:
        config()

config()

client.run(token)
```

I'm having trouble doing that because there's this error and I'm trying to figure out how to deal with it. The Regex part is an extra and is out of scope for now.

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "coroutine") to str
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'on_ready' was never awaited
```

I really have no clue how to deal with this error. I searched everywhere and Couldn't find anything similar with python.

Answer (score 0):

You've chosen a pretty hairy thing to do here, since it basically requires you to run the Discord client not in a loop, but in an once-off "log in with this token and get the user identity" scenario.

Also, you should not use Python files to store configuration data – use a data format like JSON or YAML or TOML or INI or Pickle files instead. I've chosen JSON here since it's human-editable and the module is built-in.

This is dry-coded (i.e. I can't verify this works) based on the API documentation. I'm happy to try and help if it doesn't.

```py
import asyncio
import discord
import json


async def config(token, filename):
    # Set up an event we can await on.
    ready_signal = asyncio.Event()

    # Initialize the client and hook up the event.
    client = discord.Client()

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        ready_signal.set()

    # Login and connect...
    await client.start(token)
    # Wait for on_ready to have set the event
    await ready_signal.wait()

    # Write information to console...
    print("Token:", token)
    print("Master:", client.user)

    # ... and to a JSON configuration file.
    with open(filename, "w") as outf:
        json.dump(
            {"token": token, "master": vars(client.user)}, outf, default=str
        )
    print("Saved:", filename)

    # Close the connection.
    await client.close()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(config(token="asdf", filename="config.json"))
```